# How to add app config file while create setup project in Windows C#

Tags: winforms, setup-deployment

I'm working on the windows application. Setup project has been created successfully. But i need to change the database connection while installing the set up. Kindly help ho to proceed further. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried building a Custom Action InstallHelper Configuration Editor? http://www.nullskull.com/a/783/build-a-custom-action-installhelper-configuration-editor.aspx

Comment: @abramlimpin No seems it is thrid party tool. I need any freeware or else should be doable in visual studio itself